# Convert a model in given json format

Tags: javascript, json

I have a model in which values are stored in following format:--

```
Language-count=3
      [0]
         -ID="1"
         -Name="French"
      [1]
         -ID="2"
         -Name="English"
      [2]
         -ID="3"
         -Name="Hindi"
Titles-count=2
      [0]
         -ID="1"
         -Name="Video1"
      [1]
         -ID="2"
         -Name="Video2"
Countries-count=2
      [0]
         -ID="1"
         -Name="India"
      [1]
         -ID="2"
         -Name="USA"
```

and I have to convert this model in given json format:-

```
var models = [
    {
        name: 'Language',
        values: [
            'English',
            'French',
            'Hindi'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Title',
        values: [
            'Title 1',
            'Title 2'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Countries',
        values: [
            'India',
            'UK'
        ]
    }
];
```

In above json format I have hard coded those values of Languages,countries and Titles but I have to fetch it from the above model which I have already given.

The json Format which I am getting is following:--

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "DealID": 1,
    "Title": "Position1",
    "Titles": [
        {
            "Icon": "hdtv",
            "Name": "\nWedding Bells & Farewells\n",
            "ID": 12
        },
        {
            "Icon": "hdtv",
            "Name": "Delta Farce",
            "ID": 5
        },
        {
            "Icon": "hdtv",
            "Name": "Doe B: Let Me Find",
            "ID": 9
        }
    ],
    "Episodes": [
        {
            "Icon": "episode",
            "Name": "Sparkle",
            "ID": 4
        },
        {
            "Icon": "episode",
            "Name": "Sparks Fly Out",
            "ID": 2
        },
        {
            "Icon": "episode",
            "Name": "Uploads by Filmi Gaane",
            "ID": 7
        }
    ],
    "Assets": [
        {
            "Icon": "file-o",
            "Name": "Best of Javed Akhtar - Jukebox 2 - Javed Akhtar Top 10 Hit Songs",
            "ID": 10
        },
        {
            "Icon": "file-o",
            "Name": "Ep 105 - Sin Say Shun Awards After Party additional image 1",
            "ID": 4
        },
        {
            "Icon": "file-o",
            "Name": "Ep 105 - Sin Say Shun Awards After Party box cover",
            "ID": 3
        }
    ],
    "Documents": [],
    "Languages": [
        {
            "Icon": "globe",
            "Name": "Albanian",
            "ID": 70
        },
        {
            "Icon": "globe",
            "Name": "Amharic",
            "ID": 96
        }
    ],
    "Territories": [],
    "Countries": [
        {
            "Icon": "globe",
            "Name": "Afghanistan",
            "ID": 2
        },
        {
            "Icon": "globe",
            "Name": "Albania",
            "ID": 3
        },
        {
            "Icon": "globe",
            "Name": "Algeria",
            "ID": 4
        }
    ],
    "Rights": [
        {
            "Icon": "leaf",
            "Name": "Ancillary",
            "ID": 23
        },
        {
            "Icon": "leaf",
            "Name": "Finshed Episode Rights",
            "ID": 20
        },
        {
            "Icon": "leaf",
            "Name": "Format Group - DO NOT USE",
            "ID": 63
        }
    ],
    "Contributors": [],
    "Transmissions": [],
    "Available": null
}
```

Comment: have you ever tried to do it by yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried but I was not getting the proper json format which i have mentioned above.

Comment: is your model present in some defined format? which?

Comment: then you should post your try here. No one will write your code for you. But we can help you correct what is wrong.

Comment: What language are you using? Also use websites such as pro.jsonlint.com to validate and easily correct JSON mistakes

Comment: I am writing the json code to validate online but it showing error and I am using C#.

Comment: In above question if I am retrieving length of "models"(the first json format) then the length is 3 but when I m doing the same with the json which I am getting then the length is 1157 whereas the length should be as per the nodes an "Language","Titles" and "Countries" in first JSon.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to write a simple parser and transform your data type to JSON - which would additionally allow you to reuse the parser in the future, and convert it to other data types easily for instance.

You could look at the various YAML parsers for inspiration, which would use a similiar technique for your data set's language.

Alternatively you can create a 'hack' and just keep splitting things up if your data format is always of this format, and doesn't allow arbitrary value nesting.

Answer (score -1):

List personel = new List();

```
        var client = new RestClient("your adres");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "2893de4a-457e-46a7e8efb025");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("token", "a23a80f7-3323-4594056");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        JObject deger = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        var toplam = deger["data"]["data"].Count();


        string jenp = toplam.ToString();


        for (int i = 0; i < toplam; i++)
        {
            Personeller data = new Personeller();

            data.Adi = deger["data"]["data"][i]["adi"].ToString();
            data.Soyadi = deger["data"]["data"][i]["soyadi"].ToString();
            data.tckimlikno = (long)deger["data"]["data"][i]["tckimlikno"];



            personel.Add(data);
        }
```